# How do I import Chart.js Helper Functions in Django?

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I am using chart.js with django and am receiving an error because I have not imported the chart.js helper functions getRelativePosition and getValueForPixel

```
initialize:178 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getValueForPixel')
    at tn.onClick (initialize:178:56)
    at tn.handleEvent (Chart.min.js:7:111837)
    at tn.eventHandler (Chart.min.js:7:111253)
    at n (Chart.min.js:7:110528)
    at HTMLCanvasElement.Se.<computed> (Chart.min.js:7:87040)
```

The chart.js documentation says to import with the code below, but I don't believe this can be done in Django

```
import { getRelativePosition } from 'chart.js/helpers';
```

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I am making the following assumptions:

1. You have a web application set up that is running Django on the back-end.
2. You are trying to use `chart.js` helper functions within the client-side JavaScript code of this web application.

If so, then you should be able to solve this by configuring your Django web application to serve static files. You will need to store the `chart.js` helper files in your Django static files store.

The official Django documentation on configuring and serving static files from Django can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/.

Once you have configured your Django web application to serve static files, you should be able to import the `chart.js` helper functions into your client-side HTML and JavaScript.